# Saving and integer and sharing it will all classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode5

So I am trying to develop a game, and unfamiliar with App Delegate. I may be wrong but there is a way to use the App Delegate for the following things. First of all I a way to share a integer with all classes (i.e. for currency, levels etc). But those integers would mean nothing if they were not saved so going about saving the integers is the other another question. Now does anyone have any ideas regarding the two questions that will solve them?

Comment: You can define properties in your AppDelegate and have them accessible throughout the app.  And you can back up the properties with setter methods that write the new values to an appropriate persistent location (such as NSUserDefaults).

Comment: how would I go about saving and loading them (technical wise)?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is straight-forward.  You'd generally init your properties from NSUserDefaults in the app delegate init routine, and the property setter method would write new values to NSUserDefaults (in addition to updating the property).  Not rocket science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is with NSUserDefaults. To set it the first time

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:int forKey:@"myInteger"];
```

and then do the same thing in every class any time to override whats currently there. If you just want to access it, then you can do the following (also in any class you want)

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults integerForKey:@"myInteger"];
```

Finally, NSUserDefaults saves between runs, so that answers you other question. Hope this helps

Comment: This saves it? and I just put the top in the app delegate (if so under which part)? Edit: I am assuming I put it under - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: Heres an edited version of my previous comment:  
I just put the top in the app delegate, I am assuming I put it under - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: Lol, where do I classify what integer I want it to save?

Comment: Yup, you can put it there. In my example, int is the number to save. You would insert the name of your variable or you could just put a number, say 25. Either works. Good luck

Comment: Ok so every time I want to save it or load it I just put it NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults integerForKey:@"myInteger"];? (Sorry for the plethora of questions I am new) I do not need to @synthesize anything?

Comment: to change it you need to do NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] then [defaults setInteger:yourInt forKey:@"myInteger"]... if you just want to see the value you do NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] then int theIntThatsStored = [defaults integerForKey:@"myInteger"];

Comment: Ok So  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] then [defaults setInteger:yourInt forKey:@"myInteger"] is to change it and NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] // int theIntThatsStored = [defaults integerForKey:@"myInteger"]; is to see the value. Then what do I do in the app Delegate?

Comment: I was reading a bit and would i use the app Delegate or a NSUSerDefault class?

Comment: The code above is right. NSUserDefaults is probably the easier way. You do not need to do anything in the app delegate, you can use NSUserDefaults whenever you change the int in any class you want. You just use the code above and it will set and change between runs. NSUserDefaults is pretty powerful if you ask me. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSUserDefaults` to save some values between app runs. If you don't use these very often, you could choose to only go through `NSUserDefaults`. If you use them regularly, it might be a good idea to make properties on AppDelegate or whatever singleton you want and go through these instead, only saving to `NSUserDefaults` as appropriate (`applicationWillResignActive` for instance).

Comment: Yes they will be used pretty often, so I should make properties in AppDelegate. If so how would I go about saving and loading them (technical wise)?

Answer (score 0):

If you needed more of a database approach, you could use Core Data.  But the NSUserDefaults solution works as well.